# Angularjs and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I have a dictionary:

```
{ "69": true, "72": true, "97": true, "113": false, "136": true, "189": false, "396": true, "404": false, "454": false }
```

How i can filter this data by value using angularjs? I need to get this (Only true):

```
{ "69": true, "72": true, "97": true, "136": true,  "396": true}
```

Comment: In view or controller?

Comment: Could you clarify where the usage is? If it is in an `ngRepeat` or `ngOptions` (anything where `ngFilter` can work), you can loop over (key, value) and use `filter: value`! See [ngFilter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter).

Comment: I have checkboxes list and i need to get list of all checked checkboxes.                                                        `<div ng-repeat="box in boxes" >
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="boxdict[box.id]" value="{$ box.id $}" ng-show="checkboxes"></div>`

Comment: Then `ngFilter` from my comment should work, try it out!

Comment: You shouldn't use numbers and keys in objects. It might cause some issues. Maybe an array of objects would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get a list on the code side, not the template.

```
var checked = {};
for(var key in $scope.boxes){
    if($scope.boxes[key])
        checked[key] = true; // true or $scope.boxes[key], which in your case will be true
}
// checked will be { "69": true, "72": true, "97": true, "136": true,  "396": true}
```

Depending on if you need this value to be constantly updated with each check or not, you may want to put `checked` in `$scope` and `$watch` `$scope.boxes`, running this for each change.

If you only need what is checked before you do something, its best to find what is checked before you do. Just pass `$scope.boxes` to this:

```
function findChecked(obj){
    var checked = {};
    for(var key in obj){
        if(obj[key])
            checked[key] = true; // true or obj[key], which in your case will be true
    }
    return checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = { "69": true, "72": true, "97": true, "113": false, "136": true,
    "189":false, "396": true, "404": false, "454": false }
    $scope.getValues = function(item)
    {
        var ary = [];
        for(var key in item){
            if(item[key])
                 ary.push(key);
    }
    return ary;
});
```

```
   
html:
    <li ng-repeat='c in getValues(item)'>
     {{c}}
    <li>
```